# eval - get name?

Tags: javascript, eval

Is it possible to give a name to code that I execute using eval?

When the browser loads a file and executes it, and then the code throws an exception, the browser can tell me in which file at which line the exception happened.

I want that it also can tell me where and in which `eval`ed code an exception happened. It should display the name I gave this code then.

Hope you understand what I want.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you post some of the code, people may be able to help you find a way to do what you need to do without using "eval()" at all.  That would be a much better outcome :-)

Comment: Article "Why using eval() is a bad idea" :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

and a workaround for not using it:  http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=13979

Comment: Trust me, it's not possible without eval. It's not what I'm asking for at all. Hope there is something I can do.

Comment: @FlashFan well there's no facility to do what you ask.

Comment: @FlashFan: Can you post an example? I'm not sure what you mean by "name you gave that code then".

Comment: Other question: is there a way to load & execute a script SYNCHRONOUSLY?

Comment: @FlashFan: If you have a completely different question, click the "Ask Question" (top right of page) and ask it as a question :) It's unlikely you'll get a useful response in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your name to a local var right before executing the eval and then wrap the eval in a try/catch. In the catch, you'll have both the name and the exception.

```
function evalCode(name, code) {
  try {
    eval(code);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error in ' + name + ':');
    console.log(code);
    throw e;
  }
}
```

You can't get the browser to tell you which line in the eval'd code contains the problem, as the code is treated as one distinct unit, but you can log both the name of the problem code and the problem code itself, as noted above.

Comment: This is an idea for code, that is executed synchronously, but what's about code, that is stored in a function and called later (throug an event) There is no way to catch those exceptions...

Comment: Wherever you're storing the string of code, you can also store a name. Wherever you're calling eval(), you can wrap it in a try/catch.

Comment: Edited for a little extra clarity. If this doesn't answer your question, could you be more specific about what you're trying to do and include code snippets, please?